# Как работают укорачиватели ссылок?

Tags: веб-программирование, ссылки

На текущий момент времени актуальна проблема, что URL многих документов в сети становятся очень длинными и труднозапоминаемыми. К тому же, чем больше букв - тем легче опечататься и попасть не туда. Зачастую этим пользуются мошенники.

В связи с этим, появился новый класс полезных сайтов - укорачиватели ссылок. Они позволяют создать переадресацию с короткого адреса на нужный пользователю сайт. При этом эта переадресация постоянна. Например, `goo.gl/jmKfD` указывает на страницу по адресу `http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0`

Так вот. Мне лично представляется возможным два варианта реализации подобных сервисов.

1. Сжатие ссылки по какому-либо алгоритму обработки текстовой информации.
2. Создание базы данных с ссылками, при этом доступ к каждому элементу будет производиться по номеру. Из минусов - сразу ясно, что база данных со временем будет расти. А это требования к памяти и быстродействию.

Есть ли еще какие-либо варианты?

Comment: 2 вариант мне кажется более реален. По памяти да он занимает много. Но если доступ осуществляется по дереву, то мне кажется не такая уж и потеря быстродействия идет с ростом количества ссылок

Comment: я так же за 2 вариант

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Второй вариант — т.к. напр. [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) даёт возможность самому придумать вариант короткой ссылки. Не обязательно с БД, это же просто словарь: ключ-URL. Миллион ссылок займёт около 256 мегов памяти всего. Если совсем большой сервис, можно разбить напр. на 26 серверов, по 1-й букве ключа. Где каждый сервер держит в оперативке весь набор данных своего сегмента.

Answer (score 4):

Укорачивание ссылки производится простым вычислением [хэша](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D5%E5%F8%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5) ссылки. Далее хэш ложится в таблицу ссылок по 2-му варианту с индексированием по полю хэша.

Answer (score 3):

index.html

```
<html>
<form action="ok.php" method="POST">
Ссылка: &nbsp;http://<input type="text" name="url"> <br>
Короткая ссылка: <input type="text" name="cuturl"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Укоротить"> <br>
</form>
</html>
```

ok.php

```
<?php
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $cuturl = $_POST['cuturl'];
    $BASE = "index.php";
    $info = "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://$url'>";
if ($url == '')
{
exit("Не введена ссылка!");
}
if(!is_dir($cuturl))
{
    mkdir("$cuturl", 777);
    chdir("$cuturl");
    $fd=fopen($BASE,"a+");
    fwrite($fd,$info);
    fclose($fd);
}
else
{
echo "Такая ссылка уже существует!";
}
?>
```