# Генерация токенов и их уникальность

Tags: php

Многие сервисы, например, короткие ссылки, генерируют токен, по которому доступна твоя ссылка. Или если даже взять ютуб, тоже, видео доступны по токенам - `?v=AbbASdw`.. Вопрос заключается в следующем: где гарантия, что при генерации такого рода токена, он не будет совпадать уже с существующем? Или они сначала проверяют? Какой алгоритм используется, что все токены получаются уникальными? Ведь по сути, это просто генерация строки. Каков процент совпадения?

Comment: Либо проверяют, либо это тоже своего рода инкрементальный айдишник, просто в другой системе исчисления. Хэш-функции, к которым чаще всего прибегают для создания таких штук, не могут гарантировать отсутствие коллизий, поэтому в случае нахождения совпадения надо просто регенерировать хэш.

Comment: "инкрементальный айдишник ... Хэш-функции, к которым чаще всего прибегают для создания таких штук" - как это понять? можете, если не трудно объяснить, показать. Спасибо

Comment: Насколько я понял, идея такая. (1) вы храните обыкновенное 64-битное число. Или там 128-битное. Когда надо выдать следующий токен, вы просто увеличиваете число на 1 и выдаёте его. Уникальность мы получили, но выглядит скучно, что делать? (2) мы "перемешиваем" числа: умножаем на какое-нибудь большое число, взаимно-простое с 2^64, Если верить математикам, уникальность останется. Чтобы было "с буквами", кодируем это число, например, в base64/

Answer (score 2):

В своей системе мы храним такие токены в Redis-е. Код генерации и проверок примерно следующий:

```
class Token
{
  const TTL = 60;
  const KEY = 'token:%s';

  protected $redis;

  public function __construct(\Predis\Client $redis)
  {
    $this->redis = $redis;
  }

  public function generate()
  {
    do {
      $id = uniqid();
      $key = sprintf(static::KEY, $id);
    } while ($this->redis->exists($key));
    $this->redis->setex($key, static::TTL, true);

    return $id;
  }

  public function validate($token)
  {
    return $this->redis->exists(sprintf(static::TOKEN, $token));
  }
}
```

Метод generate создает новую ID-шку токена, проверяя, есть ли уже такой идентификатор в Redis-е. Как только создал, помечает его в редисе, что уже создал с временем жизни 60 секунд (после 60 секунд данный ключ автоматом удалится из Redis-а). Метод validate проверяет: создавался ли токен в течении 60 секунд с таким названием.

Если у вас нет возможности использовать нереляционные базы данных для этого, можете хранить подобные данные в сессиях пользователя. Хотя смотря для чего он вам нужен. Возможно, вам понадобятся и реляционные базы данных для хранения этих значений.

Answer (score 2):

Разворачивая комментарий: я здесь вижу два пути. Первый - это генерация случайного хэша путем применения хэш-функции к случайному значению:

```
$hash = md5(rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX));
```

Хэш-функции служат для того, чтобы преобразовать некоторое значение произвольной длины в строку фиксированной длины, причем результат будет всегда повторятся для одинаковых input-значений (в данном примере это неважно). `md5`, например, всегда возвращает строку из 32 символов:

```
over      -> 3b759a9ca80234563d87672350659b2b
overflow  -> 0bd9f6dd716003f3818d15d2e211ee73
overflown -> 09d0a5b30b267c2504fadd43348fbba3
```

Таким образом можно сгенерировать эти символы (строку с хэшем можно обрезать до 6-7 символов, распределение символов на этом участке должно быть настолько же "случайным", как и на всей длине). Если применяется хэш-функция, то алгоритм создания хэша до безумия прост:

```
do {
    $hash = md5(rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX));
} while (hashExists($hash));
// while не успокоится, пока не будет сгенерирован несуществующий хэш.
// После этого он будет доступен в перменной $hash.
// Тут сразу же возникает проблема race conditions (грубо говоря - 
// многопоточности), но она лежит за пределами этого вопроса.

// Можно упростить до предела, хотя в некоторых местах за 
// неочевидный код бьют по пальцам
while (hashExists($hash = generateHash()));
```

Другими словами, код генерирует хеш, пока не находится свободный, т.е. с той самой проверкой.

Интереснее выглядит инкрементальный идентификатор. Каждый материал так или иначе оказывается в базе данных, и, скорее всего, имеет инкрементальный идентификатор - число, уникально идентифицирующую запись, который увеличивается на 1 (тот самый `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` в MySQL). В этом случае его можно перевести в подобную строку, просто изменив ему систему исчисления, например, используя просто первые десять букв латинского алфавита вместо цифр (или даже увеличить количество цифр).
Насколько понимаю, особого смысла у этого подхода нет (нет большой разницы, используется `video/123123` или `video/aBaB`), и вряд ли он где-то применяется.

Comment: как правильно заметили в соседнем ответе - в php даже есть функция uniqid(), которую можно использовать из коробки (однако она генерирует значение на основе микросекунд, и результат, который не проходит такого преобразования, как в хэш-функции не будет выглядеть случайной величиной - проще попробовать и увидеть. чем объяснить).

Comment: "вряд ли он где-то применяется" - у меня для внутреннего использования инкрементальный (=уникальный) ID переводится в СС с основанием 62 (цифры +латиница в обоих регистрах). Число `1234567890`, например, превращается в `1ly7vk`, `123456789` в `8m0Kx`, и тд, что как бы покороче :) а это в некоторых случаях может иметь значение.

Comment: @klopp, я бы в этом случае отдал предпочтение любому хэшу. Для человека это уже все равно перестает выглядеть, как число, а ошибка в расчетах может дорогого стоить. При необходимости можно осуществлять поиск этого хеша по префиксу, как в гите, например.

Comment: Если человек и столкнётся с этим, то только в очень редких случаях случаях copy/paste :) Задача - сократить ascii-последовательность, иначе вообще нет смысла менять сам ID.

Answer (score 0):

Был [вопрос про короткие ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/121877/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA).

Если коротко:

1. последовательные id;
2. [биективная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) функция для «интересного» перемешивания с исключением коллизий (повторов) – любой блочный код. Простейший вариант – инверсия порядка битов;
3. запись с кодированием в строку типа base64 или др. алфавитом для более короткого представления.

Comment: Вот уж для укорачивателя ссылок ничего проще инкрементального ID и не придумать.

Comment: по поводу пункта 2 и 3 - это больше похоже на способы хеширования, нежели на создание. В пункте два биективная функция (в принципе не сильно обязательно быть ей биективной), должна вызываться от чего-то! Тоже самое и в пункте 3. Все такие штуки все равно генерируются с использованием генерации случайных значений.